# Crop image using pdfcrop (has footer item)

Tags: graphics, pdf, pdfcrop

I'm trying to crop the following image and I'd like to use pdfcrop to do it.  The footer causes a problem though.  So I did something like this `pdfcrop --margin '0 0 0 -50' CircuitSimulation.pdf` and then running pdfcrop again, but it didn't work.  Are there any ways I can get pdfcrop to crop it automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would choose another solution. 
In the preamble of the document load graphicx package

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Then insert graphics from pdf in desired location as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[trim="left-margin"cm "bottom-margin"cm "right-margin"cm "top-margin"cm]{path-to-pdf-to-iclude}
\end{figure}
```

I would suggest using frame around your graphics in order to see what will stay in figure after cropping:

```
\begin{figure}
\fbox{\includegraphics[trim="left-margin"cm "bottom-margin"cm "right-margin"cm "top-margin"cm]{path-to-pdf-to-iclude}}
\end{figure}
```

The margins in the above commands are the length in cm you want to cut.

Answer (score 0):

Don´t know pdfcrop, but sometimes is better to do the layout by oneself, there are a lot of tools on the internet, like digikey dot com slash schemit... it allows you to export the designs in pdf or png, for free... or even powerpoint...
Good luck